# What graphing packages/APIs exist for Perl?

Tags: perl, charts, graphing

I'm doing some research on online Graphing packages for different languages and would like to know what current up-to-date graphing packages there are for Perl which are worth investigating

Minimum desired capabilities should include the kind which Google offers through [its API](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/)

A brief synopsis of the key benefits of the recommended package / API would be appreciated

Answer (score 7):

I've been messing around with [Chart::Clicker](http://gphat.github.com/chart-clicker/) recently.  Those translucent area charts do have something for them.

Answer (score 5):

You might find the answers to this similar question helpful [How do I create graphs in Perl on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64537/how-do-i-create-graphs-in-perl-on-windows)

If it's web based then I do like using Flash based charts.  I've used [Chart::OFC](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Chart-OFC/) and can highly recommend it.  However note there is an [Open Flash Chart 2](http://teethgrinder.co.uk/open-flash-chart-2/) on its way and a reciprocal module [Chart::OFC2](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Chart-OFC2/) as already hit the CPAN.

For good commercial Flash charting then take a look at [FusionCharts](http://www.fusioncharts.com/).  I'm currently testing this myself and it does look quite good.

For non Flash commercial alternatives then look at [ChartDirector](http://www.advsofteng.com/).  I've have used this successfully with other Perl/Python programmers in a couple of companies I've done work with.

Answer (score 3):

For graphing in Perl, I've used the [GD](http://search.cpan.org/dist/GD/) and [GD::Graph](http://search.cpan.org/dist/GDGraph/) modules. GD::Graph can produce simple bar, line, and pie charts, and output several graphics formats, including PNG.

Answer (score 2):

I second the recommendation for Chart::Clicker.  This is unquestionably the best pure Perl charting module.

BTW, I edited your tags to be "charting" instead of "graphing".  In the computer world, graphs are those things with edges and nodes, charts are pretty pictures.

Answer (score 1):

It's not open-source (or free) but check out [Chart Director](http://www.advsofteng.com/download.html) - they have a free download (no time-limit), it's cross-platform (Windows/Linux/Solaris/FreeBSD/Mac) and the charts look better than what I've seen on CPAN.

The license is only $99 US.

Answer (score 0):

My recommandation
PDL::Graphics::PLplot
PDL