# Graphing ruby gem for mac?

Tags: ruby, graph, graphing

I'm fairly new to programming with ruby and have been trying to install a gem so that I can make graphs. I've tried unsuccessfully with gruff and gnuplot as I have run into errors for both. can someone give me a detailed step by step on how install or a link to one? thanks

Answer (score 0):

there is a discussion about it here

[What graphing packages/APIs exist for Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/460329/what-graphing-packages-apis-exist-for-ruby)

Comment: Thanks, but I was looking more for a tutorial, not just what to use.