# What is a recommended R interface for Perl integration?

Tags: perl, r

I never dealt with R, so I was wondering if anyone can recommend (either from personal experience or some reviews/comparisons) which of the several Perl/R integration modules are considered "best practices"? Ideally something which could somehow qualify for production readiness.

Google shows several different modules but I am not quite sure how to evaluate the options, having zero previous R or statistics experience (the question came from a co-worker who was interested in using R)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, looks like [Statistics::R](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Statistics%3a%3aR) is probably your best bet.  It's been updated recently, Brian Cassidy is a competent developer, and it's passing its CPAN smoke tests.

There is also [Statistics::useR](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Statistics%3a%3auseR), it has been touched relatively recently, but that one doesn't seem to be compliant with CPAN's smoke testing system, which makes me a bit nervous.

That said, I haven't used either of these.

Comment: Statistics::useR just has lots of UNKNOWN reports as it doesn't bail out if the R things it needs aren't installed. Otherwise, it'd have lots of passes, as the only actually tests it has merely make sure the module can be loaded :-)

Answer (score 3):

I've personally not used it but [`Statistics::R`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Statistics-R/) looks interesting.  Its got a [3 star review](http://cpanratings.perl.org/dist/Statistics-R) on [CPAN ratings](http://cpanratings.perl.org/) and is currently going through a [face lift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3753537/is-there-any-current-review-of-statistical-modules-for-perl/3754277#3754277) with a new maintainer.

/I3az/

Answer (score 2):

What are your actual requirements in terms of

- OS that R is running on
- OS that Perl clients are running on
- type of query you plan: 'canned' or interactive

etc pp.

I have long been a fan of [Rserve](http://www.rforge.net/Rserve/) as a headless R backend but I can't recall if there was a Perl client.

Comment: Perl clients: Solaris, Perl 5.8. R running: I am assuming Solaris as well assuming it is supported. Type of query: interactive.

Comment: Solaris should work just fine. The 'Inst + Admin' manual for R has some notes on it.  Rserve would allow multiple concurrent connections when hosted on a Unix systems.  I am confused about 'interactive' though: is Perl used to present a GUI that then passes the queries on?

Comment: The queries (some of them) would originate from Perl code; so will the data to analyze. Thanks!

Comment: Hm, I'd call that 'canned' as there is code that generates the query as well as code in R that it expects to call.    Well, you have plenty of suggestions now so try some and come back with follow-ups.  Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to just read R data files, my module [Statistics::R::IO](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Statistics%3a%3aR%3a%3aIO) would fit the bill. It's a pure Perl implementation that reads both RDS and RData files.

Starting with version 0.4, released last week, you can also use it as an Rserve client.

Answer (score 1):

I've just released [Statistics::NiceR](http://p3rl.org/Statistics::NiceR). It has support for pretty much all R data types including `data.frame`s.

It's an early release, so I'd like feedback. This is what it looks like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use v5.16;
use Statistics::NiceR;
use Data::Frame::Rlike;

my $r = Statistics::NiceR->new;
my $iris = $r->get('iris');

say "Subset of Iris data set";
say $iris->subset( sub { # like a SQL WHERE clause
                  ( $_->('Sepal.Length') > 6.0 )
                & ( $_->('Petal.Width')  < 2   )
        })->select_rows(0, 34); # grab the first and last rows
```

which outputs

```
Subset of Iris data set
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
      Sepal.Length  Sepal.Width  Petal.Length  Petal.Width  Species
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
 51   7             3.2          4.7           1.4          versicolor
 147  6.3           2.5          5             1.9          virginica
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score -1):

I have recently added [Statistics::RserveClient](http://search.cpan.org/~djunkim/Statistics-RserveClient-0.06/lib/Statistics/RserveClient.pm) to CPAN. This allows perl applications to interact with a (possibly remote) Rserve server via a connection-oriented binary protocol.  You send R code to the server as strings, and the results are returned as perl data structures.

There are a number of shortcomings - we don't support long packets yet, or deal properly with certain heterogeneous structures, but the code is under active development, and it works quite nicely for our basic applications.

The code is GPL, hosted at https://github.com/djun-kim/Statistics--RserveClient